# Two columns of PDF are coming as one while trying to read it using tabula-py

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula-py

I am trying to read a input pdf using tabula-py, below is the script which i am using

```
import tabula

pdf_path = '/Users/kartikeysinha/Desktop/local-git-repository/TestPDF.pdf'
tables_ = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', guess=False)
df = tables_[0]

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
column_names = df.columns
print(column_names)
```

And I am getting following output as column names

```
Index([             'App ID Xref',                        nan,
                           'Date',                   'Broker',
       'Sub Broker Borrower Name',              'Description',
                              nan,                   'Amount',
                           'Rate',                  'Upfront',
                            'GST'],
      dtype='object', name=0)
```

But in the output you can see the first element which is `App ID Xref` are actually two different columns in my pdf, is there anyway I can workaround through it without changing the structure of the pdf I have recieved. < same for Sub Broker and Borrower Name >

Below is the attached image of the header of column in pdf

[image]

Also another small issue column names such as Settlement Date, Total Loan Amount, Common Rate... only has part of their names. How can i fix it?

Any help would be great,
Thanks & Regards

Comment: You're going to need something a little more robust to actually decompose the page to get the text out in reading order. My suggestion is to try Adobe's Extract API which will return a JSON representation of the file with structured text in reading order. You can try it on your file here. https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/dc-visualizer-app/index.html